# (Server 2008) Changing file permissions of a folder after moving it from another user

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, ntfs, file-permissions

I've recently started using a GPO to force users 'My Directory' folder to forward to c:\home on the server.  This is working fine so far.  The issue I'm running into is that since nothing like this was implemented before, files for a user are in different places on the hard drive.  So I'm having to move them into the users home directory by hand.  We don't have a ton of users so it's not an issue, plus I'm doing a few users at a time.

So when I copy/move files from these various locations into the users home directory, the user cannot open their files anymore and it gives an error regarding not having read privileges.  I figured it wouldn't be too difficult to fix, so I highlighted all the files, right clicked to go to security permissions (but it wasn't there).  So the I went to the security permissions of the folder and tried to have it 'Replace all existing inheritable permissions on all descendents...' but that didn't do anything at all.  All the files still have just admin rights to them.  I changed one file just to make sure it would work and it did, but I don't have the time to go through each and every file and change its permissions to add the proper user to it.

Any ideas on how to fix this easily?

Here are the permissions that get set for the home folder:

- domain_username, special, this folder only
- CREATOR OWNER, special, subfolders and files only
- SYSTEM/admin/Administrators, full control, This folder, subfolders and files.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review this article to see if it applies to your scenario:

**File permissions inherited from one folder persist after the files are moved to another folder in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2560088

If so, you may not want that version of shell32.dll, but the most recent version which is available here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2677246